# No funciona el método onSubmit()

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Soy nuevo en Angular por favor instruirme no se como hago para que mi formulario funcione,
estoy utilzando formGroup para aprovechar los metodos de validaciónes y utilizo el metodo get() en el formulario para obtener los datos al enviar.

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.get('email'),contactForm.get('password'))">
        <div>
            <label>Correo</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"/>
            <span *ngIf="contactForm.get('email')?.touched && contactForm.get('email')?.errors?.['required']"
            >Este campo es obligatorio</span>
            <span *ngIf="contactForm.get('email')?.touched && contactForm.get('email')?.errors?.['pattern']"
            >Introduce una dirección de correo valida</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"/>
            <span *ngIf="contactForm.get('password')?.touched && contactForm.get('password')?.errors?.['required']"
            >Este campo es obligatorio</span>
            <span *ngIf="contactForm.get('password')?.touched && contactForm.get('password')?.errors?.['minlength']"
            >Este campo debe tener un minimo de {{contactForm.get('password')?.errors?.['minlength'].requiredLength}} caracteres</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" value="enviar" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid" >Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Este es mi clase del componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../../sevices/user.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm!: FormGroup;
  public email!: string;
  public password!: string;
  public role: string;

  constructor(

    private readonly fb: FormBuilder,
    private readonly user: UserService

  ) {

    this.role = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactForm = this.initForm();
  }


  initForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$')]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    })
  }

  onSubmit(email: any, password: any): void {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    console.log(this.email,this.password);
    this.user.login(this.email, this.password, this.role).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Como veran dentro de onSubmit()
coloque dos console.log()pero no me muestra nada de nada por la consola ni tampoco errores, asi que intuyo que el metodo onSubmit() lo  estoy implementando mal o me falta algún paso porfavor se que es mucho código, pero con que me salga algo por la consola ya estoy felíz.

mi app.module es:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';;
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './components/projects/projects.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    routing,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia`(ngSubmit)` por `(submit)`.

De esta manera:

```html
<form
  [formGroup]="contactForm"
  (submit)="onSubmit(contactForm.get('email'), contactForm.get('password'))"
>
```

Asegurate de tener importado `ReactiveFormsModule` en el modulo en el que esté registrado tu componente:

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],

//... mas codigo
```

Te dejo [un ejemplo funciona aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-981kbt?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: No funciona con (submit), lo juro por dios y mi familia entera que lo tengo todo importado.

Comment: Hola Legna gracias por tu paciencia de verdad te lo agradezco, pero he copiado el código con copiaste puro y del bueno a lo bestía, el código que me has pasado a mi proyecto y mi botón de enviar esta que ni se mueve, no se si reír o llorar jajaj no puedo creer que estas cosas pasen, ahora ya no se si es un problema de versiones y si es así que triste que con cada actualización tengamos que escribir diferente.

Comment: @DaniBN Que versión de angular estas usando? Suena tonto, pero, ya reiniciaste el servidor de angular? Pararlo e iniciarlo de nuevo. Revisaste el ejemplo que te mande?

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.0.1

Comment: No es un problema de versión. Estamos usando la misma versión. Haz un ng build sobre el proyecto. En ocasiones ng serve no muestra las trazas del error por algúna extraña razón, y puede que lo que estés viendo sea código viejo, no la nueva compilación. De ahí que al hacer ng build pues revisa el código y te muestra si hay algo que no permita correr ng serve.

Comment: Ya reinicie el servidor, revise todo esta idéntico a tu ejemplo, no solo lo mire me lo copie enterito cambiándole lo que tenia que cambiarle para que compilara y nada

Comment: Ok ya intente ng build y no me aparece ningun error en la consola

Comment: Que le cambiaste para que compilara?

Comment: templateUrl: './app.component.html', por  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],   por  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],

Comment: y LoginComponent que asi se llama mi clase lo e vuelto a copiar y pegar

Comment: Puedes poner en la pregunta tu app.module?

Comment: Hola Legna, el problema no esta en mi código es un fallo interno del framework que no me permitía clikear el botón, justo ahora probé una barbaridad, puse un segundo botón con el evento (ngSubmit) justo abajo del otro y ese si funciona, le di un estilo al primer botón de opacidad 0 para que no se viera, si el primer botón lo quito el segundo falla y si al primer botón le pongo display: none también falla el segundo botón,  a estas alturas pensaras que estoy vacilando con todo lo que estoy diciendo pero definitivamente algo a mas bajo nivel esta fallando.